# PHPExcel Writter Excel2007

Tags: php

I am using PHPExcel lib for generating excel file of a table of mysql database. But I m getting a fatal error when i call a function for excel generation. The error which is comming  is given below.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' 
with message 'Could not close zip file DfEeFxMeVtUnSbKoEpTpYdYiYsEnGrQi.xlsx.' 
in /home/testcente2/domains/topcats-backend-testcenter.nl/public_html/dev/core/lib/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php:337 

Stack trace: 
#0 /home/testcente2/domains/topcats-backend-testcenter.nl/public_html/dev/core/lib/class.IExportModule.php(81): PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007->save('DfEeFxMeVtUnSbK...') 
#1 /home/testcente2/domains/topcats-backend-testcenter.nl/public_html/dev/core/lib/class.ExportModule_lang.php(59): IExportModule->_download_Excel2007() 
#2 /home/testcente2/domains/topcats-backend-testcenter.nl/public_html/dev/controllers/export.get.create.php(12): ExportModule_lang->export() 
#3 /home/testcente2/domains/topcats-backend-testcenter.nl/public_html/dev/export.php(17): require_once('/home/testcente...') 
#4 {main} thrown in /home/testcente2/domains/topcats-backend-testcenter.nl/public_html/dev/core/lib/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php on line 337
```

hello friends please tell me why this error occurred and how can we fix this error?

Comment: Can you post some code?
It seems to me that you have some problem like bad access rights on the folder where the file gets zipped.

Comment: use `phpinfo();` and see that `zlib` is enabled or not??

Answer (score 0):

from the [`PHPEXCEL Reference`](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Requirements&referringTitle=Examples)

### Requirements

- PHP version 5.2.0 or higher
- PHP extension php_zip enabled **
- PHP extension php_xml enabled
- PHP extension php_gd2 enabled (if not compiled in)

All part of the PHP package (zip) on http://www.php.net/downloads.php, should be enabled in `php.ini`

> ** php_zip is only needed by PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007,
> PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007, PHPExcel_Reader_OOCalc. In other words, if
> you need PHPExcel to handle .xlsx or .ods files you will need the zip
> extension, but otherwise not.

Comment: @Brijesh..is that an answer you want or something dfferent??